# ODE describing the motion of a mass

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the 2x2 system $$x'=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-k& -b\end{bmatrix}x$$ where $b\ge0, k\gt0$ and for a mass m=1,

a) for which values of k,b does the system have real distinct eigenvalues? Complex eigenvalues? Repeated real eigenvalues?

b) find the general solution of this system in each case.

c) Describe the motion of the mass when the mass is released from the initial position x=1 with zero velocity in each of the cases in part (a).

I solved part (a) using the characteristic equation which ends up being $\lambda^2+b\lambda+k=0$, so (by the quadratic formula) the eigenvalues are real and distinct when $b^2-4k\gt0$, repeated real eigenvalues when $b^2-4k=0$, and complex when $b^2-4k\lt0$. But going from this to the general solution of each is confusing me.

As far as describing the motion for part (c), I think that has to do with the damping? So the complex case is underdamped, the real distinct is overdamped, and the repeated eigenvalue is critically damped, but what does the motion of each of those look like?

Comment: Your question is more of physics question but for part a you did alot of work. could you perhaps try drawing a picture of the systems? do you know how to do that?

Comment: theres many pictures for all the cases a circle both eigenvalues complex spiral in and spiral out when only 1 is complex   and various combinations of exploding to infinity on the x or y axis's or going to the origin

Comment: @Moo yes, mostly for part b, the general solution. Well, I don't need the answer so much as i need help understanding how to get to the answer :)